# Creating a new Array from Normal Array and Array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object

I have two arrays, `arr1` is an array of objects and `arr2` is just a regular array. I am trying to match `arr2` values with the "original" value from the objects of `arr1` and return the "new" value into a new resulting array. There's usually more than 2 items in `arr2` and the order isn't the always same that's why I couldn't just match by the index each time.

```
let arr1 = [
        { original: "1x Adjustments", new: "ONETIME_AMT" },
        { original: "Churn", new: "CHURN_AMT" },
        { original: "Funnel", new: "FUNNEL_AMT" },
      ];

let arr2 = [ '1x Adjustments', 'Churn' ]

desiredResult = ["ONETIME_AMT", "CHURN_AMT"]
```

I tried to use the map function multiple times, but the closest I got was only returning the first element that just happened to match, maybe I need to use a for loop in it too?

```
var desiredResult = arr2.map(item => item === arr1[0].original ? arr1[0].new : '')
```

Ideally I thought the [0] could be replaced with i (index), in a for loop but not sure how to implement a for loop in a map function (or if that's even the right solution)

Comment: use `Array.find`, code:  `arr2.map(item => arr1.find(({original}) => original == item ).new)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `arr1` to a Map (`arr1Map`), and then map `arr2`, and get the `new` value from `arr1Map`:

```js
const arr1 = [{"original":"1x Adjustments","new":"ONETIME_AMT"},{"original":"Churn","new":"CHURN_AMT"},{"original":"Funnel","new":"FUNNEL_AMT"}]
const arr2 = [ '1x Adjustments', 'Churn' ]

const arr1Map = new Map(arr1.map(o => [o.original, o.new]))
const result = arr2.map(key => arr1Map.get(key))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Wow that was very insightful, I didn't know you could create a Map from an array, does that essentially take out the array from it and leave it as an object? The Javascript docs are a bit confusing

Comment: The Map's constructor accepts an array (actually any iterable)  with a structure of `[[key, value], [key, value]]`. In this case the temp array would be garbage collected after the Map is created.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use reduce for this purpose!

```js
let arr1 = [
        { original: "1x Adjustments", new: "ONETIME_AMT" },
        { original: "Churn", new: "CHURN_AMT" },
        { original: "Funnel", new: "FUNNEL_AMT" },
      ];

let arr2 = [ '1x Adjustments', 'Churn' ]

const findNew = (arr1, arr2) =>
  arr1.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if(arr2.includes(curr.original)) {
      acc.push(curr.new)
    }
    return acc
  }, [])

console.log(findNew(arr1, arr2))
```